# Payum or Omnipay Paypal credit

Tags: paypal, omnipay, payum

Does anyone know if Payum or Omnipay supports PayPal Credit?
https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/paypal-virtual-credit

Omnipay states that it doesn't support "billing agreements" but I'm not sure if thats the same thing as financing.

I cant find anything on Payum regarding Paypal credit.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal credit function is auto-appeared when buyer is from United States. It is not manually integrated but auto-appeared. PayPal is one of the payment gateway plug-ins added in many third party shopping cart platform. But whether or not PayPal is added or combined with Omnipay, you are advised to contact Omnipay for the further information.